# c# abstract classes -- "one or the other" alternate functions

Tags: c#, abstract-class

Here's one, I have an abstract class like this...

```
public abstract class SpaceshipManager
 {
 ...
 public abstract void BuildWith(ParseObject po);
 // "Or ..."
 public abstract void BuildWith(string label);
 ...
 }
```

The sense is, the derived classes must implement BuildWith a ParseObject, "OR", they can implement BuildWith using a string.

Now, at the moment I just do this ...

```
 public abstract void BuildWith(object data);
```

Which is fine - but is there a better way?

Another way to look at it, you could have two methods

```
BuildKeidranType()
BuildBastionType()
```

The concept is that derived classes have to implement at least one of these.

Is there any such thing in c#?

Comment: This seems like an interesting question but it's still really unclear what you want to do. Can you give us an example in psuedocode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use generics:

```
public abstract class SpaceshipManager<T>
{
    public abstract void BuildWith(T source);
}

public class StringBuilderSpaceshipManager : SpaceshipManager<ParseObject> { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well there is nothing like that in c#. `Generics` could have given you a way out.
But seeing that you are deriving from `MonoBehavior`, i am assuming it's `Unity` you are working with, where there are constraints like the class name must be same as the file name etc. etc. which don't give too many options for generic behaviors. So avoiding generic classes and focusing on generic methods.

The following is a very crude example using generics just for fun and might not be much better than your current example where you take the parameter as an object. Nevertheless here goes:

```
public abstract class SpaceshipManager: MonoBehaviour
{
    public void BuildWith<T>(T po)
    {
        if (ValidateBuildParam<T>())
        {
            Build<T>(po);
        }
    }

    protected abstract bool ValidateBuildParam<T>();
    protected abstract void Build<T>(T type);
}

public class DerivedA : SpaceshipManager
{
    protected override void Build<T>(T po)
    {
        //Build here
    }

    protected override bool ValidateBuildParam<T>()
    {
        return (typeof(T) != typeof(ParseObject)) ? false : true;
    }
}

public class DerivedB : SpaceshipManager
{
    protected override void Build<T>(T po)
    {
        //Build here   
    }

    protected override bool ValidateBuildParam<T>()
    {
        return (typeof(T) != typeof(string)) ? false : true;
    }
}
```

Now there are some drawbacks like the following usage wont be incorrect:

```
SpaceshipManager spMan = new DerivedA();
spMan.BuildWith<int>(5);
```

This will compile and run but would build nothing. So it would be good if you change the return type of BuildWith, return null if Validation fails or a bool `true` or `false`

Comment: (Abhi -- sorry I mentioned "MonoBehaviour" in there, I wasn't particularly thinking about it; I'll remove it from the example!! cheers, just digesting your answer...)

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such thing.

If the derived class implemented only one of the overloads, how would the caller know which one is implemented?

Comment: I bow to your experience, John, but it seems very straightforward.  All I'm saying is, in the derived class we know that: **"the derived class will be able to do either this BuildKeidranType() or this BuildBastionType() ... one of the two"**.  (Or, pretty much the same thing, overload "BuildWith" one of say two ways.)  A class talking to such a derived class would be able to check which of the two it responds to, and then, use that one.

Answer (score 1):

NO, such things which you are asking is not available in c#. In c# there is interface but you would have to implement all of the methods in derived class because if you would implement one of those caller would get confused.

Comment: I don't see hwo it would be confused, you'd just check which it responds to. The fundamental concept of as abstract class is that: **"we know you will be able to do something (say, "make an explosion") with derived classes."**  That's all it is.  I'm really just saying, you will definitely be able to make an explosion, but, two radically different types of explosion.  It seems pretty straightforward???

Answer (score 0):

As others have already told you, you cannot define abstract methods as optional to be implemented somehow.

If possible, I would suggest defining some kind of common type that can serve as input for the `BuildWith` method. For example, can the `label` string also be represented as a `ParseObject`? If not, can you think of some common abstraction for the two?

If the answer to both of these is no, that I would pose that these two methods probably shouldn't be overloads in the first place.

If the answer is yes, then you can make only one of these methods abstract:

```
public abstract class SpaceshipManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public abstract void BuildWith(ParseObject po);

    public void BuildWith(string label)
    {
        // Static method or constructor here to represent label as a ParseObject.
        BuildWith(ParseObject.FromLabel(label))
    }
}
```

In this example, ParseObject is the common abstraction. It could also be another class or interface however.

Depending on the situation, the generics option that @Lee posted could also be a good solution, perhaps combined with a non-generic base type:

```
abstract class SpaceshipManager<T> : SpaceshipManager
{
    public abstract void BuildWith(T source);
}

abstract class SpaceshipManager
{
    // Other methods here
}
```

If neither of these solutions work for you, you could always make the method(s) virtual instead and override the behavior if needed, but it's somewhat doubtful that this design makes sense in your situation.

Comment: great idea to "combined with a non-generic base type" thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement two Interfaces. `IBuildWithFromString` and `IBuildWithFromParseObject`. Then you can query which Interface is implemented by trying to cast to this Interface and in case of successand you can call the appropriate method.